# How can I make the circles clickable on MapBox?

Tags: android, mapbox

I am working with Mapbox to create a map application. I want to have some clickable circles on the map. I already got the circles on the map but i cant seem to make them clickable. I read about a circlemanager that I need to use but I cant get that to work.

I've already tried to make a Circlemanager as seen below.

```
CircleManager circleManager = new CircleManager(mapView, mapboxMap, style);

circleManager.addClickListener(circle -> Toast.makeText(container.getContext(),
                    String.format("Circle clicked %s", circle.getId()),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());
```

I wrote that code so I can test if the application detects the click. But I don't get any feedback/errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**You can have a look from GitHub repository** might it work for you.

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/testapp/activity/annotation/CircleActivity.java

Comment: Thank you for your input. But i already followed their code on github but it still doesnt seem to work.

Comment: If you elaborate a lite on what in the code is relevant this would become a better answer